# How to configure subdirectory for express using nginx?

Tags: node.js, express, nginx

I'm new to Nginx.
I am writing a web app using `Express`, the project is in directory `/home/ubuntu/wangqiuke`, here is the project structure.

```
ubuntu@VM-165-36-ubuntu:~/wangqiuke$ ls -l
total 36
-rw-rw-r--  1 ubuntu ubuntu 1958 Jun 14 15:08 app.js
drwxr-xr-x  2 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Jun 21 12:39 bin
drwxrwxr-x  2 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Jun 15 16:37 config
drwxrwxr-x  2 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Jun 12 14:42 models
drwxrwxr-x 19 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Jun 14 14:55 node_modules
-rw-rw-r--  1 ubuntu ubuntu  588 Jun 14 14:55 package.json
drwxr-xr-x  5 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Jun  6 09:44 public
drwxr-xr-x  2 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Jun 15 16:40 routes
drwxr-xr-x  2 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Jun  6 09:44 views
```

Here is my Nginx configuration:

```
    user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##
    server_names_hash_bucket_size 128;

    server {
            listen       80;
        listen       443 ssl;
            server_name  www.darenwu.me darenwu.me;

        ssl_certificate /home/ubuntu/wangqiuke/config/hacksparrow-cert.pem;
                ssl_certificate_key /home/ubuntu/wangqiuke/config/hacksparrow-key.pem;

            proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

                if ($host = 'darenwu.me') {
                    rewrite  ^/(.*)$  http://www.darenwu.me/$1  permanent;
            }   

            location ~ ^/(images/|img/|javascript/|js/|css/|stylesheets/|flash/|media/|static/|robots.txt|humans.txt|favicon.ico) {
                        root /home/ubuntu/wangqiuke/public;
                        access_log off;
                        expires max;
                }

            location /wangqiuke {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
                rewrite /wangqiuke(.*) /$1 break;
                        proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header Host $proxy_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;        
        }

    }

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # nginx-naxsi config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-naxsi
    ##

    #include /etc/nginx/naxsi_core.rules;

    ##
    # nginx-passenger config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-passenger
    ##

    #passenger_root /usr;
    #passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

When I visit this page `http://www.darenwu.me/wangqiuke`, everything is ok:

```
    Request URL:http://www.darenwu.me/wangqiuke
    Request Method:GET
    Status Code:200 OK

    Response Headers
    Connection:keep-alive
    Content-Encoding:gzip
    Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
    Date:Sun, 21 Jun 2015 06:58:47 GMT
    Server:nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
    Transfer-Encoding:chunked
    X-Powered-By:Express

    Request Headers
 Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
    Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
    Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,zh-CN;q=0.6,zh;q=0.4
    Cache-Control:no-cache
    Connection:keep-alive
    Cookie:connect.sid=s%3AF3m36gHkr5eMV0c8-LCpzQRJDDIdbf2m.UY1bqEYNILPY0c7UIQMLH9Nw4m9OgfzoHgsQ3YenQyQ
    Host:www.darenwu.me
    Pragma:no-cache
    User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.152 Safari/537.36
```

but the asset files are wrong:

```
Request URL:http://www.darenwu.me/stylesheets/style.css
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
```

Response Headers

```
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Cache-Control:max-age=315360000
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:110
Content-Type:text/css
Date:Sun, 21 Jun 2015 06:58:47 GMT
ETag:"5572507a-6e"
Expires:Thu, 31 Dec 2037 23:55:55 GMT
Last-Modified:Sat, 06 Jun 2015 01:44:26 GMT
Server:nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
```

Request Headers

```
Accept:text/css,*/*;q=0.1
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,zh-CN;q=0.6,zh;q=0.4
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:connect.sid=s%3AF3m36gHkr5eMV0c8-LCpzQRJDDIdbf2m.UY1bqEYNILPY0c7UIQMLH9Nw4m9OgfzoHgsQ3YenQyQ
Host:www.darenwu.me
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://www.darenwu.me/wangqiuke
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.152 Safari/537.36
```

I think the request url (`Request URL:http://www.darenwu.me/stylesheets/style.css`) is wrong, it should be `Request URL:http://www.darenwu.me/wangqiuke/stylesheets/style.css`.

How can I configure this in NGINX?